# How do positive/negative terminals work in a circular plug-in adapter?

Tags: battery-charging, terminal

I have an adapter with a circluar plug, then a positive and negative terminal. How does the adapter (the green piece in the picture below), which can be in any rotational orientation maintain positive and negative terminals?

Here is an image of what im trying to describe: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barrel jacks have two concentric conductors. There is a center "hole" with one conductor inside, and an outer "sheath" with a second conductor. (Note the black plastic ring separating the inner and outer conductors of the barrel.) Either one could be positive or negative, depending on the connector's polarity.

Helpfully, the polarity is marked on the brick with a *polarity symbol*. You can find out all about polarity symbols on [Wikipedia's article on polarity symbols.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_symbols)

In this case, your power brick is labeled as center-positive. The connector on the inside of the barrel will have a higher voltage than the connector on the outside.  Center-positive is, in my experience, the orientation of the vast majority of DC barrel jacks.

The barrel-to-screw-terminal adapter likely also follows the center-positive convention, but we can't know for sure just by looking at your picture.

To be 100% certain, just get out your multimeter and measure the voltage across the screw terminals (with the power supply plugged in). Put your red lead on the terminal labeled (+) and the black (common) lead on the terminal labeled (-).  The voltage will either read positive or negative; if it's negative, your adapter is actually center-negative and thus the connections are reversed.

Answer (score 2):

It's radially symmetric and concentric. The middle polarity (pin) is always the same, as is the outer (sleeve), irrespective of how it's inserted. There's no "left" or "right" side. Just "inner" and "outer" for the connections to be made.

Answer (score 1):

According to the diagram on the supply, the hollow center of the output connector on the cable is the + output, and the exposed metal sleeve is the - output.  That part is fixed by the manufacturer, and is in fact the most common polarity assignment.

Separate from that is the adapter.  There might be something molded into its body that says which cage block position is connected to which part of the barrel connector, the center pin or the shell.  If there is nothing to see, then you must use an ohmmeter to determine which cage block position goes where.  There is no industry standard assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter has molded polarity signs on it because it's designed to be used with that specific power brick.  Now, *most* barrel plugs for power use + center and - sleeve convention but that's not guaranteed, you have to check the markings on the brick or check with a multimeter.